# SharePoint: users cannot see document create or last modified dates

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-services, attributes

As the SharePointServices admin user for my organization, I can see all the attributes created and last modified date on documents.  However, all non-admin users cannot see them.  For example, all they see is `Created at 04/09/2010 09:24 by` (blank).  Other than giving all users admin rights (which is not going to happen), how can I enable users to see file attributes?  Even those that have contribute rights on library cannot see the attributes.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

By default, and on every SharePoint site I've ever setup or used, these attributes are readable by all users that have at least Read access (and probably even View, though I've rarely restricted users to that permission).  There's a few possibilities I can suggest, but none that I've ever experienced firsthand:

- Have you altered the permissions of the site collection, site or document librar(ies)?
- Have you altered the default Permission Levels in your site or site collection?
- Have you installed any third-party add-ons for SharePoint - e.g. anything that enhances/alters document management or user management?
- Is the AD synchronization working correctly, so that all the usual attributes of each user account (name, email, etc) are coming across correctly?

Comment: No on point 2; no on point 3; yes on point 4.  As for point 1, the permission definitions haven't been modified.  Does something else need to be checked under the permission level?